# Why are downvoted questions closed without giving the author the chance to respond to voters?

Tags: discussion, downvote-reason

My question has been closed and downvoted just because the sense of my question was not understood. Now I do not have the possibility to explain what I meant and I do not have the possibility to tag people who downvoted the question to let them know the point of the question.

The question was closed because was "too broad" but it had to be too broad. Mine was more than a question: I already had a solution to the question (and I had written it) but I wanted a conversation with colleagues about the way they approach that topic. By "topic" I mean something broader than a question. So I ask you what "too broad" means?

I remember was possible have discussions (not asking questions) on Stack Overflow. Is this not possible anymore?

Please give us the possibility to reply to people that downvote.

Comment: *"I remember was possible have discussions (not asking questions) on stackoverflow... is not possible anymore?"* - No...it's not.

Comment: Just ask a new and better question. You can refer to the closed question so people know the context.

Comment: I think you confuse downvoting and closevoting (a question, even with -20, is not closed for downvotes, only for closevotes), also tagging and pinging.

Comment: _If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here._ - from [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: If you are referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294992/best-approach-for-archiving-emails), your question was either too broad or primarily opinion based. Really not fit for SO, you are looking for a different kind of site to have that kind of discussion.

Comment: If anything, discussion maybe fit in chat. Definitely not as a question on main and it never has been, really.

Comment: And _replying to downvotes_ and its variants has been discussed many, many times. Since votes are anonymous by design, and commenting on votes is actually discouraged for good reasons, the idea goes counter to the way things operate in SO.

Comment: @n8te, if you go on reading, it has been also written: 
*Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:

inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”;
tend to have long, not short, answers;
have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone;
invite sharing experiences over opinions;
insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references;
are more than just mindless social fun.*

I think my question matched 4 out of 6 points

Comment: You could edit your question to make it on topic and wait for reopen votes. If that doesn't work you could consider using chat. SO is really not the place for discussions.

Answer (score 11):

> The question was closed because was "too broad".. but it had to be too
>   broad... Mine was more than a question... I already had a solution to
>   the question (and I had written it) but I wanted a confrontation with
>   collegues about the way they approach that topic. With topic I mean
>   something broader than a question. So I ask you what "too broad"
>   means? I remember was possible have discussions (not asking questions)
>   on stackoverflow... is not possible anymore?

Stack overflow is for narrow and specific programming problems, not for general discussions or critical interrogation of solutions. That's why the "too broad" close reason exists.

If you believe your question to be closed unfairly, you can edit it and either ping the close voter directly in a comment asking them to reconsider (if it was a 1 person duplicate closure), or wait for your question to enter the reopen queue.

> Please give us the possibility to reply people downvote...

This has been suggested and declined on here dozens of times.

Comment: Yes I wanted to ping close voters in a comment but I couldnt, perhaps how someone said I make confusion between down-votes and close-votes

Answer (score 4):

You can reply to close-votes.

One way is to address to close voters directly by [pinging them in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) (if they were the sole close-voters). Of you can comment generally under your question, defending why your question shouldn't be closed. The close voters may or may not read your comments (they may have found your post through review, for example, so maybe they aren't coming back to your question).

But usually, the best way to handle this is to edit your question so it is a better fit with StackOverflow, and can be re-opened.

After a question is closed or put on hold, the first edit will put it to the re-open queue, where reviewers will consider if your edit pushed your question over the closable threshold.

Replying to downvoters (or to votes in general) doesn't really work as an idea, since votes are anonymous by design, and commenting on votes is discouraged to reduce friction.

There are many, many discussions about the subject on votes and comments. Best is probably to start reading [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin), and look around in meta for more examples.

Regarding the specific main question that brought up this issue... trying to address either close-voters or down-voters wouldn't have helped you much. The question was simply off-topic for StackOverflow, and the best course of action is to learn the rules of the site and post questions that follow more closely the our rules for topicality.

Much more often than not, this will be the case. So attempting to communicate with close-voters wouldn't be productive in any way. The most best course of action is to read the close-reason, re-read the rules, and try to think in which ways you question could be changed (if at all) to fit the site's model

Comment: Yes I wanted to ping close voters in a comment but I couldnt, perhaps how someone said I make confusion between down-votes and close-votes